# 404 page without index.php in url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, apache

I read many article on SE but excuse me for not having knowledge of servers. I have tried turning off "Use Web Server Rewrites", but no change. I get 404 page which says "Not found", to which i used my knowledge of SE posts, which said to use index.php before the url e.g

> www.abc.com/index.php/men/new

and this work, but i have to put index.php manually. Why is it happening and how can i fix it because my "use web server rewrites" is turned off too.

Comment: add .htaccess file to your root directory which comes with fresh installation.

Comment: Enable apache `mod_rewrite` and add .htaccess file to root. Then restart apache server

Comment: If you don't **want** to use the rewrites, you could change the base urls in *system > configuration > web* to "http(s)://example.com/index.php/" instead of "http(s)://example.com/"